# Why does nmap send two packets in order to test a single port

Tags: nmap

I run nmap with root privileges using sudo so I assume it has full access to creat raw sockets. Wireshark shows two packets used to test a single port when I used the command

```
sudo nmap 192.168.110.153 -p21
```

Is that normal behavior? why?

[image]

```
sudo nmap 192.168.110.153 -p21 --packet-trace

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-19 19:18 BST
SENT (0.0447s) ARP who-has 192.168.110.153 tell 192.168.110.155
RCVD (0.0450s) ARP reply 192.168.110.153 is-at 00:0C:29:F4:05:E0
NSOCK INFO [0.2450s] nsi_new2(): nsi_new (IOD #1)
NSOCK INFO [0.2450s] nsock_connect_udp(): UDP connection requested to 127.0.1.1:53 (IOD #1) EID 8
NSOCK INFO [0.2460s] nsock_read(): Read request from IOD #1 [127.0.1.1:53] (timeout: -1ms) EID 18
NSOCK INFO [0.2460s] nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT SUCCESS for EID 8 [127.0.1.1:53]
NSOCK INFO [0.2460s] nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: WRITE SUCCESS for EID 27 [127.0.1.1:53]
NSOCK INFO [0.2740s] nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: READ SUCCESS for EID 18 [127.0.1.1:53] (46 bytes): *%...........153.110.168.192.in-addr.arpa.....
NSOCK INFO [0.2740s] nsock_read(): Read request from IOD #1 [127.0.1.1:53] (timeout: -1ms) EID 34
NSOCK INFO [0.2740s] nsi_delete(): nsi_delete (IOD #1)
NSOCK INFO [0.2740s] msevent_cancel(): msevent_cancel on event #34 (type READ)
SENT (0.2751s) TCP 192.168.110.155:45170 > 192.168.110.153:21 S ttl=39 id=28633 iplen=44  seq=3053138125 win=1024 <mss 1460>
SENT (0.3754s) TCP 192.168.110.155:45171 > 192.168.110.153:21 S ttl=46 id=8796 iplen=44  seq=3053072588 win=1024 <mss 1460>
RCVD (0.2759s) TCP 192.168.110.153:21 > 192.168.110.155:45170 RA ttl=64 id=14442 iplen=40  seq=0 win=0 
RCVD (0.3756s) TCP 192.168.110.153:21 > 192.168.110.155:45171 RA ttl=64 id=14443 iplen=40  seq=0 win=0 
Nmap scan report for 192.168.110.153
Host is up (0.00047s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp closed ftp
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:F4:05:E0 (VMware)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.50 seconds
```

Comment: Add `--packet-trace` to the command for more insight on what it is doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a `libpcap` problem with queuing packets before delivering them to Nmap. Notice the difference in ordering of packets between Wireshark and Nmap; even though the timestamps are the same, the order of printed lines shows that the packets were delivered to Nmap *after* the second SYN packet was sent. We recently had/have a [problem with libpcap 1.5.3](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/34) (and possibly the 1.6 branch, haven't tested) on newer Linux kernels related to the packet ring/TPACKET interface not delivering packets when they arrive. What's the output of `nmap --version`?

The underlying problem is a bug in Linux, which was [already fixed but not backported](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg314667.html). We solved this issue in development by upgrading libpcap to version 1.7.3, which has some workarounds.

Comment: Nmap version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org )
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Compiled with: liblua-5.2.3 openssl-1.0.1f libpcre-8.31 libpcap-1.5.3 nmap-libdnet-1.12 ipv6
Compiled without:
Available nsock engines: epoll poll select

Comment: @Matka Yes, that exactly matches what I'd expect to see from this bug. You can try compiling from source yourself, since our included libpcap seems to be unaffected.

Comment: compiling from source solved that! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Given you screenshot, it seems that `[R.]` packets are filtered before hitting the machine you are scanning from and nmap used its retransmission feature since the first `[S]` packet didn't received any answer.

You can disable this using `--max-retries 0`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does nmap send two packets in order to test a single port?

Normally: because of the three-way handshake required to [establish a TCP connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) ... send SYN -> receive SYN-ACK -> send ACK

In this case: because the response from 192.168.110.153 is `RST, ACK`  or in other words: a connection to port 21 is rejected. Probably nmap is slightly persistent and tries twice before taking no as an answer.

Comment: Is this normal? I have not found anything that suggests something similar i.e. nmap tries twice

Comment: Just tried with an open port at the target machine, same issue, two packets